# How to capture the tag element in HTML code by mouse click

Tags: jquery, html, html-parsing, mouseevent

In some websites, there are some input form and submit button that can process a `GET` or `POST` method like:

```
<form method="GET" action="/index.php">
  <input type="HIDDEN" name="mode" value="search">
  <input type="TEXT" name="term" value=""> <input type="SUBMIT" value="Search">
</form>
```

Here I want to create a function in my web application like a function in FireBug: when I move my mouse to this input form and click, the application can show which part of html code is. 
For example: if I move my mouse to input form and click in original web page, I can see a result shown in my application: `<input type="TEXT" name="term" value="">`

No matter which language or framework I need to use, I just want to this result to be shown on a web application, maybe another web page.

Comment: and can you please show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: and where are you stuck?

Comment: Oh,I did nothing at all currently... I just want to know any method can approach this "Mouse-GET-TAG" function...

Comment: I am just a beginner for web application maker....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am also a new student of Javascript but may my code help ..
you should learn about `this` keyword here is the link [this tutorial](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

and i have created this simple function which give you code of all input text fields you can use this function for all input fields..

http://jsbin.com/AjiQAMo/2/watch?html,js,output

Comment: Oh...thank you for your question. However, I find there contain "onclick="shwinputtypetext(this)"function in form...But my target is on other's website. For example, the code as I showed on my question. I don't know how it works for that...

Comment: ohhh now i failed.. :)